# How to remove default left and right padding in react native

Tags: react-native

[Image of Text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHcTm.png)

Want to remove the left and right padding of forget password Text.Please Help

```
    import React, { useState } from "react"
```

import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, Button, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from "react-native"

const Practice = (props) => {

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

function onTappedLogIn() {

}

function onTappedForgetPass() {

}

function onTappedShow() {

}
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.containerView}>
        <View style={styles.upperView}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.middleView}>
            <Text style={[styles.text, { marginTop: 30 }]}>Email Address</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)} />
            <Text style={styles.text}>Password</Text>
            <View style = {styles.passTextInputView}>
                {/* <Text>Show</Text> */}
                <TextInput style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(pass) => { setPassword(pass) }} />
                
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onTappedLogIn()}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                        Log In
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.forgetPass}>Forget Password?</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>

)
```

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
containerView: {
flex: 1,
// justifyContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: 'grey'
},
middleView: {
flex: 0.45,
flexDirection: 'column',
backgroundColor: 'white',
marginLeft: 25,
marginRight: 25
},
upperView: {
flex: 0.30,
justifyContent: 'flex-start',
alignItems: 'flex-end',
marginRight: 15
},
text: {
marginLeft: 15,
marginTop: 15,
marginBottom: 20
},
textInput: {
borderBottomWidth: 1,
borderBottomColor: 'black',
marginLeft: 15,
marginRight: 15
},
button: {
padding: 15,
backgroundColor: 'green',
marginTop: 30,
marginLeft: 15,
marginRight: 15,
borderRadius: 25,
marginBottom: 20
},
buttonText: {
textAlign: "center",
fontWeight: 'bold',
color: 'white',
textDecorationLine: "underline"
},
forgetPass: {
textAlign: 'center',
textDecorationLine: 'underline',
includeFontPadding: false,
flex:0
},
passTextInputView:{
// flex:.3
}
})

export default Practice

Comment: please explain your issue, unable to understand ?

Comment: Have you tried setting `paddingHorizontal` to zero?

Comment: Yes I have tried paddingHorizontal zero but its not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to set the text containers style to `flex:0`

Apply `alignitems:'center'` to the text container ([sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/text-container-shrinking))